# Adding jQuery library to WebStorm

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webstorm

I recently started using WebStorm and I wanted to use jQuery inside of it. Now I followed like the general guidelines on the internet to install the library but it still doesn't recognize the `$` symbol when I use it.

What should I do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: in your `<script>` `src` URL, `.js` extension is missing, thus the browser can't resolve the jquery library and ReferenceError is thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download a copy of the JavaScript files on your file system and include it as external lib to your project (even if you use CDN versions of the libs with your project). Then WebStorm/PhpStorm/IntelliJ etc. can analyse the code (works with the .min-versions as well) and offers code completion etc.

Even more simple example with PhpStorm:
[image: Simple example with PhpStorm (comparable to WebStorm)]

A cleaner method is to add it as external library, if you do not want to have a copy of jQuery in sources. However, I do not know, if WebStorm has a comparable option like that, as it has less functionality than PhpStorm or even IntelliJ.

[image: Using external libraries in PhpStorm]

Comment: I just noticed that the admin changed my post before I tried to add more pictures, let me try again.

Comment: Please see screenshot. Really don't know what's so hard to understand with that.

Comment: Ok, let me try it out.

Comment: What do you mean with a 'copy of your javascript files'? Do you mean jquery source document you point to in the image?

Comment: The site says that I can download Jquery. I found jQuery in the list and downloaded it. Since it said global I assumed I could just open my document with $(function()... and use jQuery. For some reason that didn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, I found it. I changed my jquery code to a local file and simply didn't know it needed a .js at the end. Now it works. This drove me insane for two hours hahaha. Thanks for helping.

Comment: That's what I was suggesting all the time. Please mark my answer as "correct".

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a reference to jquery on your html page.
2. Use "Download library" command from context menu. I found it at "src" attribute of "script" tag.

- Allow Webstorm to download the library via npm.

3. Now you see an entry for jquery in the Project view below the folder "External Libraries".